# no puedo hacer login en heroku

Tags: django, heroku

tengo un problema, ya estoy listo para subir mi app de django a Heroku pero al momento de hacer `heroku login` y que me pida apretar cualquier tecla para que se abra una pestaña para logear, este solo se queda pesando y nunca abre la pestaña para hacer el login, ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar debes asegurarte que tu conexion a internet no es demasiado debil. Esto me ha dado problemas parecidos en el pasado. Si no es así seria bueno resetear tu contraseña de heroku. Tambien puede servir loguearte en consola con el comando `heroku login -i`, presionas enter para aceptar el email que muestra la pantalla y luego ingresas tu contraseña, finalizas con enter y deberia conectarse al tu cliente heroku. Al menos a mí me funcionó. Espero te sirva de algo...saludos